# Browser displays JSON response instead of HTML with JSON in network tab

Tags: json, express, request, get

I am following this video: https://youtu.be/5TxF9PQaq4U?t=600
When he makes a GET request to localhost:8383/info the JSON {info: "Text"} is shown inside the network-tab but the browser still displays the HTML page. When I make the GET request to localhost:8383/info, the browser displays the JSON but not the HTML. How can I get the same result as him?

Index.html (inside "public" folder)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input id="input" type="text">
        <button id="get">Get</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    const input = document.getElementById("input")
    const getbtn = document.getElementById("get")

    getbtn.addEventListener("click", getInfo);

    async function getInfo(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8383/info", {method: "GET"})
        console.log(res)
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Server.js

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const port = 8383

app.use(express.static("public"))

app.get("/info", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({info: "Text"})
})

app.listen(port, ( ) => console.log("Server started"))
```

[This is what the browser displays on localhost:8383/info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09JFy.png)

I have tried to make the GET request to localhost:8383 (without info) but then the response is the HTML file, not {info: "Text"}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed two places

#1 Need to add CORS in `server.js`

```
app.use(cors());
```

#2  Need to add DOM element in `index.html` and update it in script.

```
    <p id="message">
        The message will go here
    </p>
    ...

document.getElementById('message').textContent = JSON.stringify(info);
```

This is full code.

```
const express = require("express")
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express()
const port = 8383

app.use(cors());

app.get("/info", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({info: "Text"})
})

app.listen(port, ( ) => console.log("Server started"))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="">
        <input id="input" type="text">
        <button id="get">Get</button>
    </form>
    <p id="message">
        The message will go here
    </p>
</body>
<script>
    const input = document.getElementById("input")
    const getbtn = document.getElementById("get")
    getbtn.addEventListener("click", getInfo);
    async function getInfo() {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8383/info');
        return await response.json();
    }
    getInfo().then(info => {
        document.getElementById('message').textContent = JSON.stringify(info);
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Result - ran `GO Live` extension in VS.code and `node server.js`

[image]